# Pip install frhdtools throws egg_info error

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install a pip module called "frhdtools". When I try to install it by running `pip3 install frhdtools`, I get this error:

```
Collecting frhdtools
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/8b/026dd40093d1b67f15e30bff9bf8ed64d133c38cee996ba702cf941b6259/frhdtools-0.0.4.1.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\users\\gabri\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-gvvrdp\\frhdtools\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\users\\gabri\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-gvvrdp\\frhdtools\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gvvrdp\frhdtools\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-gvvrdp\frhdtools\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        version=open(versionFile).read(),
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'VERSION'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I got this error on an Ubuntu installlation about a month back and I ended up having to download the source and just run a file inside it. I am on Windows 10 now, and I was hoping it was just an issue with Ubuntu, but I guess not. I have made sure that it is Python3-compatible (in fact it is python3 only). Any thanks is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: there seems to be a problem with your python installation, because you said you used pip3 but the log clearly show python27 being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a broken package. It's not including the `VERSION` file that is required by `setup.py`. I'm not familiar enough with Python on Windows to tell you how to fix the package, but assuming this is what you're looking for, you can just download it (or clone it) directly from [the GitHub page](https://github.com/mnurzia/frhdtools), where the VERSION file is included.